# Compute the derivative using chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

> Let $z=f(u,v)$ where $u=xy$ and $v=\frac{x}{y}$ such that $f$ is second differentiable.
>
> Compute $\tfrac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial x\partial y}$ and
> $\tfrac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial x^2}$.

My attempt for $\tfrac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial x\partial y}$ is to use the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}x+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{-x}{y^2} \\
\implies &\dfrac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right).\dfrac{-x}{y^2}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}.\dfrac{-1}{y^2}.
\end{align*}
I don't know how to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right)$. I wanna change $x$ to $u, v$ to use the hypothesis $z(u,v)$ is second differetiable.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule, \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = y \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \frac 1y \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}, \text{ and} \\[6pt]
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = x \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} - \frac{x}{y^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}.
\end{align*}
Thus, \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( x \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} - \frac{x}{y^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right) \\
&= x \left( y \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} + \frac 1y \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}\right) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}  - \frac{x}{y^2} \left(y \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} + \frac 1y \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}\right)  - \frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\\
&= xy \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} - \frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} - \frac{x}{y^3} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you explain why we have the third equality?

Comment: @AlexNguyen I can't! Because it's wrong. Editing now.

Comment: @AlexNguyen Should be OK now.

Comment: In the fourth equality, how you can change $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}$?

Comment: @AlexNguyen I've passed $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ through, using the product rule, and noting that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = y \frac{\partial}{\partial u} + \frac 1y \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ as shown above.

Comment: In short: $\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial~}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)&=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u~^2}+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v~\partial u}\\&=y\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u~^2}+\dfrac 1y\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u~\partial v} \end{align}$